# Is cross product of del, $\nabla \times \nabla$, zero in vectors?

Tags: vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors, vector-fields

I came across a vector term like

$$ \nabla \cdot (\nabla \times \mathbf{F}) = 0 $$

So I though to solve it like

\begin{align*}
M
&= \nabla \cdot (\nabla \times \mathbf{F}) \\
&= \mathbf{F} \cdot (\nabla \times \nabla) - \nabla \cdot (\nabla \times \mathbf{F}) \\
&= \mathbf{F} \cdot (\nabla \times \nabla) - M, \\
\vphantom{\Big(}
2M &= \mathbf{F} \cdot (\nabla \times \nabla) = 0.
\end{align*}

Here I suppose $\nabla \times \nabla$ must be **zero**. So

$$ \nabla \cdot (\nabla \times \mathbf{F}) = 0 $$

Is this is true that $\nabla \times \nabla$ (This is meaningless)?

Comment: $\nabla \times \vec F$ is a vector.  Thus, $\nabla(\nabla \times \vec F)$ is a dyadic field.  And $\nabla \times \nabla $ is meaningless.  However, $\nabla \times (\nabla \Phi)=0$ for any twice differentiable scalar field $\Phi$.

Comment: @MarkViola How can we prove that `∇(∇ X F) = 0 ` ? I agree this `∇×∇ ` is meaningless .

Comment: It isn't $0$. .It's a dyadic.

Comment: I edited your question assuming that the lower dot ($.$) stands for the (formal) inner product notation. Hope this does reflect your original intent. Also, as for your question, notations for vector differential operators like $\operatorname{grad}=\nabla$, $\operatorname{curl}=\nabla\times$ and $\operatorname{div}=\nabla\cdot$ are just algebraic convenience, so you need to play with them with great care.

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product),

> If two vectors have the same direction (or have the exact opposite
>   direction from one another, i.e. are not linearly independent) or if
>   either one has zero length, then their cross product is zero.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this is true that `∇ x ∇ = 0`  ?

Yes!

Read more in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities#Second_derivatives_2).